# Combination of \alert and \pause for beamer class

Tags: beamer

I'm preparing a presentation where i want paragraphs to be hidden, if they weren't mentionet yet. Therefore I'm using a

```
\pause
```

between paragraphs. In addition i'd like to highlight the latest paragraph. Therefore I'm using

```
\alert<+>{here comes a paragraph}
```

The result then is,

```
\alert<+>{here comes a paragraph} \pause
\alert<+>{here comes another paragraph} \pause
\alert<+>{three is the magic number} \pause
```

which means that i need to press the next-page-button two times, when I need to jump to the next paragraph. Is there a posibility to combine alert an pause without needing two keypresses?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10):

You can say `\alert<1>` to have the text alerted on page 1. Then you get

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \alert<1>{here comes a paragraph} \pause

  \alert<2>{here comes another paragraph} \pause

  \alert<3>{three is the magic number} %\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I commented the last `\pause` since it will generate one more page without any alerts.

An alternative is to use an `itemize` with no bullets. Then you can set the alerts for each uncovered item,

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}[<alert@+|+->]
  \item[] here comes a paragraph
  \item[] here comes another paragraph
  \item[] three is the magic number
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

This will add a space to left of the paragraph. To get rid of that one can use `list` instead, but that does not seem to be supported by `beamer` so the `alert` and step functionallity has to be set onthe items.

```
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \leftmargin=0pt
      \labelwidth=0pt
      \labelsep=0pt
    }
  \item<alert@+|+-> here comes a paragraph
  \item<alert@+|+-> here comes another paragraph
  \item<alert@+|+-> three is the magic number
  \end{list}
```

If it is something used a lot it can be put in an environment with the paragraphs as a command

```
\newenvironment{MyList}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \leftmargin=0pt
      \labelwidth=0pt
      \labelsep=0pt
    }}
  {\end{list}}
\newcommand\MyItem{\item<alert@+|+->}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test 4}
  \begin{MyList}
  \MyItem here comes a paragraph
  \MyItem here comes another paragraph
  \MyItem three is the magic number
  \end{MyList}
\end{frame}
```

All alternatives give more or less the same result (there is some more space to the left in the second version):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `\pause` - they introduce an additional overlay as `<+>` itself already creates a new one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \alert<+>{here comes a paragraph}

  \alert<+>{here comes another paragraph}

  \alert<+>{three is the magic number}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]